# Splitting a date range into different fiscal years

Tags: sql, db2, date-range

I have a dataset:

```
Quantity         Start date               End date
   1              2012-03-28              2012-05-30
   7              2012-08-15              2012-12-15
```

I would like to sum and group their quantity together using the fiscal year, which starts at the 1st of each April and end 31st of March next year. I.e.

```
 Fiscal Year    Quantity    
  2012            3000
  2013            1788
```

I attempt to create an attribute fiscal year but encounter the issue that the date range may fall between 2 fiscal year. ( First row of original dataset and for that instance, we would need to count the quantity twice, once in 2011 and the other in 2012.)

May I know if there are ways to perform such operations?

Thank You!

Comment: You may use your base table alone without an additional table like `fiscalYear` below. Do you need such a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following by creating a fiscalYear table. The logic breaks if the quantity start date and end date span more than two fiscal years.

```
fiscalYear(Year, StartDate, EndDate)

insert fiscalYear values
(2011, "2011-04-01", "2012-03-31"),
(2012, "2012-04-01", "2013-03-31"),
(2013. "2013-04-01", "2014-03-31")

select t1.Year, sum(t2.Quantity)
from fiscalYear t1
inner join myTable t2 on (convert(datetime, t2.StartDate) >= convert(datetime, t1.StartDate)
and convert(datetime, t2.StartDate) <= convert(datetime, t1.EndDate) )
or
(convert(datetime, t2.EndDate) >= convert(datetime, t1.StartDate)
and convert(datetime, t2.EndDate) <= convert(datetime, t1.EndDate) )
group by t1.Year
```